# having a route between two gps coordinates

Tags: python, group-by, pandas-groupby

Good Evening,
I have gps coordinates for each trip and i'm trying to have a line between each point for each trip..
I'm using this code, but still doesn't work , if i delete `groupby(id)` it works but i get a line also between points from not the same tripId ..

```
tooltip = "Click me!"
for i in range(11):
    folium.Marker(df.groupby('id')
        [df['latitude'][i],df['longitude'][i]], popup=df['id'][i], tooltip=tooltip ).add_to(map)
    
    route = folium.PolyLine(df.groupby('id')
        [[df['latitude'][i],df['longitude'][i]],[df['latitude'][i+1],df['longitude'][i+1]]],
        tooltip = "trip"  ).add_to(map)
```

my dataframe looks like that :

```
    longitude   latitude    id
0   5.184529    52.032471   66168
1   5.184513    52.032047   66168
2   5.184468    52.031559   66168
7   5.183908    52.027328   66168
8   5.175724    52.084732   89751
9   5.175513    52.084743   89751
10  5.174866    52.084713   89751
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest separating adding the polylines and the markers to the map. Markers can be added individually, the polylines as lists of geolocations. Since the latter needs to be clustered by `id`, it makes sense to add them per group, after the groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
import io

data = '''    longitude   latitude    id
0   5.184529    52.032471   66168
1   5.184513    52.032047   66168
2   5.184468    52.031559   66168
7   5.183908    52.027328   66168
8   5.175724    52.084732   89751
9   5.175513    52.084743   89751
10  5.174866    52.084713   89751'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+')

tooltip = "Click me!"
m = folium.Map(location=[52.031559, 5.184468],
              zoom_start=15)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']],
                        popup=row['id'],
                        tooltip=tooltip
                       ).add_to(m)
    
for index, row in df.groupby('id',as_index=False)[['latitude','longitude']].agg(list).iterrows():
    loc = list(zip(row.latitude, row.longitude))
    folium.PolyLine(loc, tooltip = "trip").add_to(m)
```